# static pages on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How do I build static pages on wordpress?
I use wordpress, and it keeps looking like a blog, with a navigation bar on the side which I don't like.  I want a "static website" like look.  with articles, not blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a theme for that. In your theme you can make it look like anything you want. If you're blog is on wordpress.com just pick a theme from the gallery.

or if you host your own blog, you can download any of the free themes or make your own! It's pretty easy.

These links should help 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty huge question.  Very open-ended.

The layout of your site (looking like a blog vs. a static site) is entirely dependent on your theme.

An easy way to get started is to use the default twentyten theme, and add widgets to your sidebar (WP admin > Appearance > Widgets).  This will stop the default sidebar from displaying.

Next, you can create a static page in WP Admin > Pages and then use that page as your default page, WP Admin > Settings > Reading > Front page displays...

From there on out, it's really a matter of making your theme look like you want it to.  f there's something that WordPress can't do out of the box, search Google or the [WordPress Plugin Repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) for what you want to do.